# How to extrude a segment from a curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I have added more segments to a Bezier curve, and when I try to extrude that segment, instead of having one line, I get 2 lines swirling. I need to have only one, how's this possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think with curves, you're better off to select two adjacent points and extrude them together - you will probably still have to fix the handles somewhat, but you'll avoid the "dual loopty-loop" that comes with a single point extrusion.

Comment: When I extrude the 2 points, it causes a gap in between, was this the method you suggested, or did I understand incorrent? https://ibb.co/zx1Tqcy